# ScalikeJDBC How can sort query by aggregate function?

Tags: sql, scala, scalikejdbc

my project have next tables: Posts, Users, comments. Post one-to-many comments, Post many-to-one users. I want to get All posts with comments and user and order by comments count. First problem was uncorrect limit, but I fixed this by sub-queries. But how can I sort posts by count queries ?

This is my DSL operation in scalikeJDBC:

```
   val x = SubQuery.syntax("x").include(v, p, u)
      DB readOnly { implicit session =>
        withSQL {
          select.all(p,u,v)
            .from(Post as p)
            .leftJoin(Vote as v)
            .on(p.postId, v.postId)
            .join(User as u)
            .on(p.userId, u.userId)
            .join{
              select(p.result.*,count(v.voteId))
                .from(Post as p)
                .leftJoin(Vote as v)
                .on(p.postId, v.postId)
                .join(User as u)
                .on(p.userId, u.userId)
                .groupBy(p.postId)
                .as(x)
            }.on(x(p).postId, p.postId)
        }
          .one(Post(p.resultName, u.resultName))
          .toMany(
            rs => Vote.opt(v)(rs),

          ).map{
          (p:Post,v:Seq[Vote])=> {
            p.copy(votes = v)
          }
        }.list.apply
      }
```

I know how to do it in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM blog.POSTS p LEFT JOIN BLOG.POST_VOTES pv  ON p.POST_ID = pv.POST_ID JOIN (SELECT p2.POST_ID as id, COUNT(pv2.VOTE_ID) "count" FROM BLOG.POSTS p2 LEFT JOIN BLOG.POST_VOTES pv2  ON p2.POST_ID = pv2.POST_ID GROUP BY p2.POST_ID) r ON p.POST_ID = r.id ORDER BY r."count";
```

How can i order by `count(v.voteId)` in DSL ? `.orderBy(x(count(v.voteId)))` not working